# MSB4018 Resolve Package Assets task failed unexpectedly, while trying to learn how to use stacks in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Hello and thanks for any help in advance

The error code above is occurring when trying to learn stacks.
I am on windows 11, most other questions online I have seen are using macs, and point out issues with mac version so as far as I can tell they cant help me here.

I have tried so far:

- Reinstalling Visual Studio on two different drives, one SSD and the other HDD
- Deleting folders like obj and bin
- Repairing visual studio through the installer

  ```
    {

        Stack stack = new Stack();

        stack.Push('g');
        stack.Push('n');
        stack.Push('i');
        stack.Push('t');
        stack.Push('e');
        stack.Push('e');
        stack.Push('r');
        stack.Push('g');


        Console.WriteLine("Item have been added to the stack");

        DisplayStack(stack);



        Console.ReadKey();
    }

     static void DisplayStack(Stack stack)
    {
        foreach (char item in stack)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Stack Content is: {0}", item);
        }
    }
  ```

And the awfully long full error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\Coding\Components-tools-SDK\NuGetPackages'.
   at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(LockFile lockFile)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() pushpopstacks   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.406\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    241
```

Again, I appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this Page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-msb4018-the-resolvepackageassets-task-failed/559252).

The solution is to [Manually added the empty folder C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\Nuget and recompiled the VS it should work.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-msb4018-the-resolvepackageassets-task-failed/559252#T-N713794)

Comment: Just wanted to add, one of the first lines of the error "Unable to find fallback package folder" ( location and name of missing folder) so you just have to add the proper name. Mine was D:\Coding\Components-tools-SDK(add a folder here called NuGetPackages)